# How to prove that $\log_2 \log_2 \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{\log_2 n} < \log_2 \log_2 n$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

How to prove (may be by induction) that $\log_2 \log_2 \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{\log_2 n} < \log_2 \log_2 n$ ?

Comment: What is $n$ assumed to be?

Comment: @user49640 integer greater than any desirable contant

Comment: I do not think this inequality holds: $\log_2\log_2\frac{n}{2} = \log_2\log_2 n - \log_2\log_2 2= \log_2\log_2 n$.

Comment: @Gordon $\log \log \ n/2 = \log (\log n - \log 2)$ and $\log(a-c) = \log a + \log(1-c/a)$

Answer (score 1):

For this to make sense we must have $\log_2 \frac n2>0$ i.e. $n>2$.

Now writing $x=\log_2 n$ the statement reduces to $\log_2(x-1)+\frac 1x<\log_2 x$ (for $x>1$).

We have $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\log_2y=\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\frac{\log y}{\log 2}=\frac{1}{y\log 2}$. This is greater than $\frac 1y$ (since $\log 2<1$). So we have
$$\log_2 x-\log_2(x-1)=\int_{x-1}^x\frac{\mathrm dy}{y\log 2}>\int_{x-1}^x\frac{\mathrm dy}{y}>\int_{x-1}^x\frac{\mathrm dy}{x}=\frac 1x.$$
This proves what we wanted.